# Waterfall chart using MVC3 devexpress controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I am very new to web development using devexpress controls . Today I was asked to create a waterfall chart in my web application. I am developing the app as mvc3 using devexpress controls.

Is there any controls available in devexpress? Or should I move for any other option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is solved. I used "side by side range bar" devexpress control for fulfilling my task

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google unearthed [a link on the DevExpress website](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3572) that shows an example on how to use their 'Range Bar Series View' to draw a waterfall chart.  There's nothing showing what the output of this example would look like, but it might be worth a try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraCharts;

namespace WindowsApplication53
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateTable();
            pivotGridControl1.RefreshData();
            pivotGridControl1.BestFit();
        }
        private void PopulateTable()
        {
            DataTable myTable = dataSet1.Tables["Data"];
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Aaa", DateTime.Today, 7 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Aaa", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), 4 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Bbb", DateTime.Today, 12 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Bbb", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), 14 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ccc", DateTime.Today, 11 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ccc", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), 10 });

            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Aaa", DateTime.Today.AddYears(1), 4 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Aaa", DateTime.Today.AddYears(1).AddDays(1), 2 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Bbb", DateTime.Today.AddYears(1), 3 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Bbb", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddYears(1), 1 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ccc", DateTime.Today.AddYears(1), 8 });
            myTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ccc", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddYears(1), 22 });
        }

        private void pivotGridControl1_CustomChartDataSourceData(object sender, DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotCustomChartDataSourceDataEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        List<Series> list = new List<Series>();
        private void chartControl1_BoundDataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChartControl chart = (ChartControl)sender;


            if (chart.Series.Count < 1) return;
            for (int i = chart.Series.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Series s = chart.Series[i];
                foreach (SeriesPoint point in s.Points)
                {
                    double width = point.Values[0];
                    point.Values[0] = GetPreviousSeriesSummary(chart, i, point.Argument);
                    point.Values[1] = point.Values[0] + width;
                }
            }


        }

        private double GetPreviousSeriesSummary(ChartControl chart, int seriesIndex, string argument)
        {
            double summaryValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < seriesIndex; i++)
            {
                Series s = chart.Series[i];
                foreach (SeriesPoint point in s.Points)
                {
                    if (Equals(point.Argument, argument))
                        summaryValue += point.Values[0];
                }
            }
            return summaryValue;
        }

        private void chartControl1_CustomDrawSeriesPoint(object sender, CustomDrawSeriesPointEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```